# Save results exlusively in another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to apply the same function with different parameters to a single column and save the results in a separate data.table, without updating/modifying the original one:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(43)
dt <- data.table(
         a = sample(c("aaa","bbb","ccc"),15,replace = T),
         year=sample(c("2015","2018"),15,replace=T),
         b = sample(c("o","r","s","c","d","f"),15,replace = T),
         variant=sample(c("osdcf", "osc", "offsco", "osc", "odfsc", "oc"),15,replace = T)
       )
stringsim_methods=c("lv","osa","dl","lcs","jw","qgram")
for (x in stringsim_methods) { 
         dt1=dt[,(x):=stringsim("oscdf",variant, method=x),by=.(variant,year)]
         }
```

However, because of how assignment works, the original data.table will be updated as well, and dt1 will include all the other columns and rows from dt.
The only way i was able to come up with around this was to initialize dt1 with one method and then use the for loop to calcualte the others:

```
dt1=dt[,.(lv=stringsim("oscdf",variant, method="lv")),by=.(variant,year)]
for (x in stringsim_methods) {
  dt1=dt1[,(x):=stringsim("oscdf",variant, method=x)]
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this:

```
   variant year        lv       osa        dl       lcs        jw    qgram
1:   osdcf 2018 0.6000000 0.8000000 0.8000000 0.8000000 0.9333333 1.0000000
2:  offsco 2015 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5454545 0.6972222 0.7272727
3:   osdcf 2015 0.6000000 0.8000000 0.8000000 0.8000000 0.9333333 1.0000000
4:   odfsc 2015 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.6000000 0.4666667 1.0000000
5:  offsco 2018 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5454545 0.6972222 0.7272727
6:   odfsc 2018 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.6000000 0.4666667 1.0000000
7:      oc 2015 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.5714286 0.8000000 0.5714286
8:     osc 2018 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.7500000 0.8666667 0.7500000
9:     osc 2015 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.6000000 0.7500000 0.8666667 0.7500000
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please ad a minimal implementation of the `stringsim` function to your question? THX!

Comment: maybe `dt[, lapply(stringsim_methods, function(x) stringsim("oscdf",variant, method=x)), by=.(variant, year)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `stringsim` function looking like this

```
stringsim <- function(x,variant,method) paste(method, variant, sep = ":")
```

a working solution could be:

```
dt3 <- dt[,
          lapply(stringsim_methods, function(x) stringsim("oscdf", variant, method = x)),
          by = .(variant, year)]
data.table::setnames(dt3, 3:length(dt3), stringsim_methods)
```

which results in

```
> dt3
   variant year        lv        osa        dl        lcs        jw        qgram
1:   osdcf 2018  lv:osdcf  osa:osdcf  dl:osdcf  lcs:osdcf  jw:osdcf  qgram:osdcf
2:  offsco 2015 lv:offsco osa:offsco dl:offsco lcs:offsco jw:offsco qgram:offsco
3:   osdcf 2015  lv:osdcf  osa:osdcf  dl:osdcf  lcs:osdcf  jw:osdcf  qgram:osdcf
4:   odfsc 2015  lv:odfsc  osa:odfsc  dl:odfsc  lcs:odfsc  jw:odfsc  qgram:odfsc
5:  offsco 2018 lv:offsco osa:offsco dl:offsco lcs:offsco jw:offsco qgram:offsco
6:   odfsc 2018  lv:odfsc  osa:odfsc  dl:odfsc  lcs:odfsc  jw:odfsc  qgram:odfsc
7:      oc 2015     lv:oc     osa:oc     dl:oc     lcs:oc     jw:oc     qgram:oc
8:     osc 2018    lv:osc    osa:osc    dl:osc    lcs:osc    jw:osc    qgram:osc
9:     osc 2015    lv:osc    osa:osc    dl:osc    lcs:osc    jw:osc    qgram:osc
```

There is no need to use `:=` if you just want to "select" original or calculated columns to store them in a new data.table.

Answer (score 2):

Two changes will make it cleaner:

1. In the first step it seems that you are not really summarizing, so you only need unique combinations of the two variables
2. You can replace the for with lapply in j

```
stringsim <- function(x,variant,method) 1
dt_red <- dt[,unique(.SD),.SDcols=c("variant","year")]
dt_red[,(stringsim_methods):=lapply(stringsim_methods,function(x) 
stringsim("oscdf",variant, method=x)),.(variant,year)]
```

Not sure what your stringsim function does so I just created a simple one that takes the same inputs

Comment: not a `data.table` approach but working as requested :-)

Comment: hehe right, let's do the unique inside. It looks pretty data.table now, doesn't it @RYoda?

Comment: Very nice, what I really like is the "injection" of the wanted column names via `(stringsim_methods) :=` which avoids my second step calling `setnames`!